# kendo ui how to change series markers types after create chart

Tags: charts, kendo-ui, telerik, series

ive created kendo ui chart :

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<script>
$("#chart").kendoChart({
  series: [{
    type: "line",
    data: [1, 2, 3]
  }]
});
</script>
```

and now after i created the chart i want to change the series markers type property the options are : circle" , "square", "triangle" , "cross"
how can i do that ? 
I tried the next section

```
var chart = $("#chart").data("kendoChart");
for (var i = 0; i < chart.options.series.length; i++) {
    chart.options.series[i].markers.type = "square";
}
chart.refresh();
```

and of course it does not work ... 
the error is :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'type' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!
I tried some modifications of your code. It is correct only problem is that **markers** object does not exists when you assigning type property. It means that you have to create markers object and then set type or set some default markers when initializing.

[Not working demo](http://dojo.telerik.com/UxoLO/2) - Check console log. It writes exactly same error.

[Solution 1](http://dojo.telerik.com/UxoLO) is create markers object when initializing chart.

[Solution 2](http://dojo.telerik.com/UvugO) is create marker object and assign into series object.